# How do you resolve missing type errors in the @polkadot/api v7.x.x packages?

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

Upgrading from:

```
// package.json
"@polkadot/api": "^6.7.2",
"@polkadot/types": "^6.7.2",
```

to:

```
// package.json
"@polkadot/api": "^7.7.1",
"@polkadot/types": "^7.7.1",
```

causes major compilation problems when using TypeScript on the front-end. There are a lot of missing types from the `@polkadot/types/lookup` folder (for example: `Error: node_modules/@polkadot/api-derive/balances/types.d.ts:3:15 - error TS2305: Module '"@polkadot/types/lookup"' has no exported member 'PalletBalancesBalanceLock'`).

Is there a problem with the packages or is there some way to fix these errors? (Note, I'm currently only hitting the Substrate node template. I don't personally have any custom runtime logic in there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [CHANGELOG of the 7.x release](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/releases/tag/v7.0.1), you must add the line:

```
import '@polkadot/api-augment';
```

and the types should work again.

Comment: Wow, that was such a simple fix. Thanks for pointing me to the release notes. I should've thought of that.

Comment: If anybody comes wondering, the notes say to put this import "somewhere". For an Angular project, that somewhere was `polyfills.ts`.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have a tiny, single-file PoC to just get account information and I'm getting a huge pile of typescript errors (840), even with the above import as the top line. Can anyone give me a push? This is with `@polkadot/api` version `9.2.4`.